# Finding an optimal svg path from opencv findContours()

Tags: python, opencv, svg, vector, vision

I am trying to get a SVG path from handwritten curves and geometric figures on paper.

For this, I'm using the `findContours()` function from `OpenCV`. Saving the contours as an individual SVG file, I get the following result:

[image: Original image]
 [image: Image with contours]

In the case of an overlapping curve like this one, I can't use either the inner contour or the outer contour as the "bone" of the curve. I would like to find a way to extract the center curve or the bone of this curve from the contour points. I've tried stroking the contours enough so that they overlap, then converting it to raster and then back to SVG, without much success. Is there an efficient way to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for "centerline tracing". Have a look at how it can be done with Inkscape: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113560/convert-parallel-paths-into-one-in-inkscape or try this tool: https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace